# Elements in ring of algebraic integers.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $K$ is a number field and $\mathfrak{O}_K$ the ring of algebraic integers.
Let $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal, for each $\alpha\in{\mathfrak{O}_K}$ if

$(\alpha)=\mathfrak{p}_1^{n_1}\cdots{\mathfrak{p}_r^{n_r}}$ with $n_i\in{\mathbb{N}}$ (ideal factorization)

define:

$v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha)=n_s $ if $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_s$; $0$  in otherwise.

My question is: Exists $\pi\in{\mathfrak{p}\setminus{\mathfrak{p}^2}}$ such that $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\pi)=1$?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is $\pi \in \mathfrak p \setminus \mathfrak p^2$, since otherwise we would have $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p^2$, contradicting unique factorization into prime ideals (the ring of integers is a Dedekind domain).
That such a $\pi$ satisfies $v_{\mathfrak p}(\pi) = 1$ follows from your definition of the valuation, since $\mathfrak p$ divides $\pi$ but $\mathfrak p^2$ does not.

Comment: Sorry, "since $\mathfrak{p}$ divides $\pi$ but $\mathfrak{p}^2$ does not." why?

Comment: If $I$ and $J$ are ideals in a Dedekind domain, then $I \supset J$ if and only if $I$ divides $J$, i.e. $I = JJ'$ for some ideal $J'$. To divide is to contain. So $\pi \in \mathfrak p$ implies that $\mathfrak p$ appears as a factor in the decomposition of $(\pi)$, and $\pi \not\in \mathfrak p^2$ means that $\mathfrak p^2$ does not divide $(\pi)$.